# Сглаживание графики в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, графика

Есть следующий минимально компилируемый пример:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsLineItem>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

    QGraphicsLineItem* line = new QGraphicsLineItem(0, 100, 200, 100);
    QPen pen;
    pen.setWidthF(2.0);
    line->setPen(pen);
    scene->addItem(line);

    QGraphicsView view;
    view.setScene(scene);

    QTransform transform;
    transform.rotate(3);
    view.setTransform(transform);
    view.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    view.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

На экране отображается следующая картинка:

[image]

Уже здесь видно что линия выглядит нечёткой. Особенно хорошо это выглядит при некотором увеличении:

[image]

Как можно увеличить качество отрисовки графики в Qt? В частности, наклонных линий.

Comment: ну вообще наклонная линия является "нечеткой" из-за свойства `Antialiasing` без него нечеткость пропадет, но линия станет ступенчатой. Увеличить четкость, но так, чтобы линия не стала похожей на лестницу в растре, имхо, невозможно (по крайней мере стандартными средствами).